# I have a Pandas DataFrame Column that contains values in list - how can I get the values out of the list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list

I have a Pandas DataFrame Column that contains values in list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rule': [["zero"],["a,b,c"], "d"]})
df['Rule']=pd.DataFrame(df['Rule'])

    Rule
0   [zero]
1   [a,b,c]
2   d
```

I want to get the values out of the list as follow

```
    Rule
0   zero
1   a,b,c
2   d
```

how shall I proceed?

Comment: What other items can you have in the Series? long strings? numbers?

Comment: The lists always contain one item, right?

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest approach is to use a list comprehension and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
df['Rule'] = [x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in df['Rule']]
```

Variant with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Rule'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) else x)
```

*Note that `[0]` requires at least one item in the list, if you can have none, then use `x[:1]` instead.*

Updated `df`:

```
    Rule
0   zero
1  a,b,c
2      d
```

Comment: worked - thanks @mozway